# Prove that every compact manifold is homeomorphic to a subset of some Euclidean space.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation, manifolds, compact-manifolds

I am trying to prove the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** Every compact manifold is homeomorphic to a subset of some Euclidean space.

The manifolds I'm considering are the most general (without any smooth, PL or any structures). Here's a formal definition:

> $n$-**Manifolds.** An $n$-manifold $\mathcal M$ is a second-countable, Hausdorff topological space such that every point $p\in\mathcal M$ has a neighborhood $U\subseteq\mathcal M$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Here's my (incomplete) attempt at a proof:\

> *Proof.* Suppose $\mathcal M$  is a compact $n$-manifold. By compactness, $\mathcal M$ has a finite open cover, say, $U_1,\dots,U_k$. By definition, we are guaranteed that each of these open subsets is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. That is, we can choose homeomorphisms $\phi_i:U_i\to\mathbb R^n$ for each $i$. We recall that since $\mathcal M$ is compact, it is also paracompact and hence admits a partition of unity subordinate to this open cover, say, $(\psi_i)_i$. Then I'm lost...

My idea was to use the functions $\phi_i$'s and $\psi_i$'s to construct a homeomorphism $\Phi:\mathcal M\to\mathbb R^j$ for some $j$ using the [Pasting Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) (also known as Gluing Lemma). But I don't know how to use that lemma to construct $\Phi$ and show that is it a homeomorphism. I have already spent over two days in trying to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: @Jakobian : I'm aware of the famous Whitney's Embedding Theorem. But currently, I am looking for a proof using the above mentioned facts (homeomorphisms and partitions of unity and the pasting lemma) only.

Comment: What you are trying to prove, for smooth manifolds is known as [Whitney embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) and it is farm from trivial. For compact metric spaces, these can also embedded in Euclidean space due to covering dimension argument, see  Hurewitz-Wallman's "Dimension Theory". Again, nontrivial.

Comment: Compact manifolds*. Not all compact metric spaces are finite-dimensional

Comment: Yes, I meant compact manifolds.

Comment: The proofs for explicit bounds on $N$ for which an $n$-dimensional manifold can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^N$ are hard to prove (e.g. Whitney embedding theorem), but this one is more straightforward (!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take open finite open cover of $X$ by sets homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, say $U_1, ..., U_k$. For each $i$, let $f_i:U_i\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a homeomorphism. By considering the one-point compactification $\mathbb{R}^n\cup\{\infty\}\cong S^n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can extend $f_i$ to a continuous map $f_i:X\to \mathbb{R}^n\cup\{\infty\}$ where $f_i$ sends $X\setminus U_i$ to $\infty$. Verify this.

The map $f(x) = (f_1(x), ..., f_k(x))$ is then an embedding, since it's a closed injective continuous map. As mentioned above, the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$ naturally embedds into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so this gives an embedding of $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks for this simple but elegant proof without even invoking the existence of the partitions of unity. This is exactly the kind of proof I was trying to find. By the way, did you mean "$\mathbb{R}^n\cup\{\infty\}\cong S^{n}$" instead of "$\mathbb{R}^n\cup\{\infty\}\cong S^{n+1}$" ? Because it is $\mathbb S^n$ which naturally embeds into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry. Yeah that's what I meant

Comment: I just came back with a slight confusion. Can you elaborate on how to show that $f(x)$ defined above is injective? I know why it's closed and continuous but don't know how to check injectivity in this case.

Comment: If $f(x) = f(y)$ and $x\in U_i$, then $f_i(x) = f_i(y)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ so $y\in U_i$. But recall that $f_i$ is a homeomorphism from $U_i$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $x = y$.